# Using Hibernate to initialize flyway's schema_version table

Tags: hibernate, primary-key, flyway

We are currently using flyway as a standalone component to manage our database migrations of current customers. For new customers, we'd like to start deploying our application with flyway's schema_version table, along with an entry for the current version.  Hibernate is currently used by our application to initialize the database (during installation), and provide an orm.

When I tried to create the xml mapping for schema_version, I found out that Hibernate [requires a primary key](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id), and according to the following output from `show create table schema_version;` there is no primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schema_version` (
`version_rank` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`installed_rank` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`version` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`script` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
`checksum` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`installed_by` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`installed_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`execution_time` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`success` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
KEY `schema_version_vr_idx` (`version_rank`),
KEY `schema_version_ir_idx` (`installed_rank`),
KEY `schema_version_s_idx` (`success`) 
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My question is, would flyway continue to operate correctly if I created an extra field for a primary key, or set a composite key in schema_version?

Here is current Hibernate mapping xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.hp.cp.psp.persistence.data" catalog="orion" default-lazy="false">
<class name="Schema_VersionDO" table="schema_version" lazy="false">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>

    <id name="id" type="int" /><!-- added to satisfy hibernate (id|composite-id) -->
    <property name="version_rank" type="int" index="schema_version_vr_idx"  not-null="true"/>
    <property name="installed_rank" type="int" index="schema_version_ir_idx" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="version" type="string"  length="50" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="description"  type="string"  length="200" not-null="true" />
    <property name="type"  type="string"  length="20" not-null="true" />
    <property name="script" type="string" length="1000" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="checksum" type="int"/>
    <property name="installed_by" type="string" length="30" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="installedOn" not-null="true">
        <column name="installed_on" sql-type="timestamp" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" />
    </property>
    <property name="execution_time" type="int"  not-null="true"/>
    <property name="success" type="byte" length="1" index="schema_version_s_idx"  not-null="true"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Help or advice is as always, greatly appreciated. Thanks
Brad

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Hibernate for this. `Flyway.init()` does exactly what you need.

Comment: As always, thanks for you quick response! 

The current decision with our software is flyway will not be used during install or be integrated into the main app. I'll have to convince them that it should be, to initialize and interface to flyway properties. They would like to see the database version from the UI and integrating into hibernate seems unsafe and too much work.Thanks again.